# How to set dropdown select through data-attribute or text?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop, if-statement

I am working on a JavaScript function which should copy shipping address form values to a billing address form section in case both are identical.

I wanted to rely either on a data attribute, text or innerHTML to set the select, since option id changes once a selection has been made.

```
<select id="order_bill_to_land" name="order[bill_to_land_id]"><option value="">select a country</option>
  <option value="1" data-land="1">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="2" data-land="2">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="3" data-land="3">Albania</option>
```

My JavaScript function is:

```
let land = document.querySelector("#country").getAttribute('data-country');
let bl = document.querySelector("#order_bill_to_land");

for (let i = 0; i < bl.options.length; i++) {
  if (bl.options[i].text === land) {
    return console.log("if loop working");
    bl.selectedIndex = i;
    break;
  };
}
```

Which produces `0`, because the if conditional does not work which I deduce from the fact that I am unable to log to console.

Why is that so?

I found a shorter version for selecting the selectedIndex:

```
bl.selectedIndex = [...bl.options].findIndex (option => option.innerHTML === land);
```

but it produces `-1`. Since it is so nicely condensed I am unable to find out why it does not work.

How can I get this working?

Thank you in advance!

**Update**

The for loop works, since I was able to log all options of `bl` by putting a console.log outside of the if statement.
This is what I did:

```
for (let i = 0; i < bl.options.length; i++) {
  console.log(land);                            // Line 185
  console.log(bl.options[i].text);              // Line 186
  if (bl.options[i].text === land) {            // Line 187
    bl.selectedIndex = i;
    break;
  };
}

console.log(bl.selectedIndex);                  // Line 203
```

Which produces the following console output:

```
...
[Log] Germany (dev.js, line 185)
[Log] Zambia (dev.js, line 186)
[Log] Germany (dev.js, line 185)
[Log] Zimbabwe (dev.js, line 186)
[Log] 0 (dev.js, line 203)
```

In debug I can check `bl`, `options[i]` and `land` in line 187, but not `.text`. I do not know if this is normal. Since I am able to log them outside of the if-statement this should work, or?

Theoretically it should loop through `bl` and when `bl.options[i].text` (or `.innerHTML`) matches `land` break the loop and output `bl.selectedIndex = i` and therefor set the select form.

**Update 2**

In console I get:

```
let bl = document.querySelector("#order_bill_to_land")
undefined
let land = document.querySelector("#country").getAttribute('data-country');
undefined
land;
"Germany"
bl.options[84].text
"Germany"
```

So both are type String, but when I test:

```
land === bl.options[84].text;
```

I get `false`.

I suspect `land` and `bl.options[i].text` end up being different object types and following [developer.mozilla.org on "Using the equality operators"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). This generates a runtime error. I do not know yet how to solve it.

Comment: Try to console.log in for loop (not inside if) and check difference `console.log(bl.options[i].text, land)`

Comment: @aserferov. I already did and it logs through all country options so the loop works, but the if statement does not and I do not know why!

Comment: not just country, country and land. Aslo remove `return` statement inside for loop. Its    
 Illegal return statement

Comment: @aserferov. Thanks. The return ended up there through error. I added more details above. As I said the for loop works, but somehow the if statement does not.

Comment: Try different country name for land. Here is working example [https://jsfiddle.net/mfakwz2L/](https://jsfiddle.net/mfakwz2L/)

Comment: When setting `let land = "Germany";` it works. I guess `land` and `bl.options[84].text` are different object types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators. But I do not yet know how to solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187050/discussion-between-seju-and-aseferov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @aseferov I found the problem:

`land` had a tailing invisible character which was produced by ruby on the server through:

```
data-country="<%= @order.land.name %>"
```

Which produced

```
let land = document.querySelector("#country").getAttribute('data-country');
```

After land.trim() the conditional worked.